# Show that $\log_a x$ (for some $x > 1$), as a function of $a$, is monotonically decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

> Let $a>0$. Let define logarithm function with base $a$ as a inverse function of $f(x)=a^x$ i.e. $log_a x = f^{-1}(x)$. Next we fix $x>1$ and define $g(a)=log_a x$. Show that function $g(a)$ is monotonically decreasing.

How I should answer this?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you. I got your point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y >0$ and consider

$f(y)= \log_y (c)$ , where

$c$ >1 is a constant.

$z:= \log_y (c)$ then $y^z = c$;

$z \ln y = \ln c$, or $z= \dfrac{\ln c}{\ln y}$.

With $f(y) = \dfrac{\ln c}{\ln y}$ we get:

$f'(y) =(-1) (\ln c)(\ln y)^{-2}(1/y).$

Since $c>1$ we have $\ln c >0$, and

$f'(y)<0$, hence decreasing

Answer (score 0):

If $b>a>1$, then $a^{\log_ax}=x$, whereas$$a^{\log_bx}=\left(\frac ab\right)^{\log_bx}b^{\log_bx}=\left(\frac ab\right)^{\log_bx}x<x,$$since $\frac ab<1$. Therefore, $\log_bx<\log_ax$.

Comment: Thanks, this is elegant solution. Should I still say something about discontinuity of logarithm function at point a=1 or can I omit that in this kind of question? I have used to think monotonicality at intervals so is it correct to say that g(a) is monotonically decreasing at the intervals it is defined? Or is the question actually unclear?

Comment: @Oscar What I wrote has nothing to do with continuity. However, I made a mistake (I shall edit my answer). What I did actually assumes that $1<a<b$; in fact, if we allow $a$ and $b$ to belong to $(0,1)$, then my proof will not work, because then $\log_bx$ will be negative and therefore$$a<b\implies\frac ab<1\implies\left(\frac ab\right)^{\log_bx}>1.$$

Comment: Actually your proof works very well also for interval (0, 1). In that case it just show that $a^{log_b x} > a^{log_a x}$ and while $a \in (0,1) \Rightarrow log_b x < log_a x$. However, what I'm now hesitating here, is whether I can just say that function is decreasing, should I say it's decreasing at the intervals it's defined or simply that function is not decreasing?

Comment: @Oscar It is increasing in both intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,+\infty)$. Note, however, that it is not even defined at $1$.